Error for Invalid length parameter passed to SUBSTRING function
I have a table called tblPeople and this is created as shown below and filled with some data:
CREATE TABLE tblPeople 
(   
    LongName NVARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
)

INSERT INTO tblPeople (LongName)
VALUES ('OrgHarvest Inc (Home Shopping Latino Inc prior to 07/2018)'),
       ('Unknown Organisation');

Then, I have a query which causes an error:
SELECT 
    myValue = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(p.LongName, CHARINDEX('(', p.LongName) + 1, 
    (CHARINDEX('prior to', p.LongName) - CHARINDEX('(', p.LongName)) - 1)))
FROM 
    tblPeople p (NOLOCK)

I get this error:

Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

I've tried few things but couldn't work out. Can you advise if I'm doing something wrong. The error is with the row "Unknown Organisation"
Do I have a condition or what to do here?

Debug it was selecting the values you are passing to substring

Without a [mre] we can't do that for you

Have now added some example values @DaleK

Why don't you try debugging it as I suggested?

Recommended reading: Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere

The error is telling you the problem here. Some of your strings don't have the strings you are looking for, so what are you expecting to occur for those exactly? How, for example, do you you the 1st to minus 1st character of the string 'Unknown Organisation'? For the string '1ST INDEPENDENCE FINANCIAL GROUP INC (De-listed 09/2008))' you are asking for the characters between character 39 and character -39. There are plenty of examples of how to deal with this error and dealing with strings that don't have the value you are looking for; what about that content didn't you understand?

Yes @ThomA - you are right and I've added that to question. How to omit that check or for values that don't match?

A case expression?

NULLIF is normally useful (wrapped around the CHARINDEX).

Does this answer your question? Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function while trying to sort by alphanumeric value

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

As you clearly understand now, the problem is the fact that the length parameter you pass to the substring method is a negative number, in case the longName doesn't contain the prior to substring (or in case it's before the first ( char in the string).
This can be solved using a condition - using case or iif, or it can be solved using a combination of nullif, abs, isnull and len.
In both examples I'm using cross apply so that I only have to write each charindex call once. IMO, This makes the code much more readable
Using a condition:
SELECT LongName  
  ,myValue = IIF(PriorToIndex > OpenParenthesisIndex+1, 
      LTRIM(RTRIM(
      SUBSTRING(
          LongName, 
          OpenParenthesisIndex,
          (PriorToIndex - OpenParenthesisIndex - 1)
      )
  )), LongName)
  
FROM tblPeople  
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('prior to', LongName) As PriorToIndex) As pti
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('(', LongName) As OpenParenthesisIndex) As osi

Using NullIf/IsNull:
SELECT LongName  
  ,myValue = LTRIM(RTRIM(
      SUBSTRING(
          LongName, 
          OpenParenthesisIndex,
          ISNULL(NULLIF(Length, -ABS(Length)), LEN(LongName))
      )
  ))
  
FROM tblPeople  
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('prior to', LongName) As PriorToIndex) As pti
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('(', LongName) As OpenParenthesisIndex) As osi
CROSS APPLY (SELECT PriorToIndex - OpenParenthesisIndex - 1 As Length) As ssl

You can see a live demo on db<>fiddle
